# Is it possible to write a Perl foreach loop in a single line?

Tags: perl, foreach

Is it possible to use a single line `foreach` loop in Perl?

```
$hash{$thing}++ foreach my $thing (@things);
```

I know this is possible with many other commands such as,

```
die "Invalid file!\n" if (open($Handle, "file.txt"));
```

I know that open statement maybe broken :)

Comment: @Zaid: "inline a loop"? Maybe it's just me, but I found the previous title more descriptive... :/

Comment: on your second statement: change `if` to `unless` or use the more common idiom (and 3arg open and lexical handle) `open my $handle, '<', 'file.txt' or die "Error opening file: $!";` of course use `'>'` if you want to open the file for writing rather than reading.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Almost.  In the foreach suffix, you must use $_:

```
$hash{$_}++ foreach @things;
```

Or equivalently (since `for` and `foreach` are aliased for syntax):

```
$hash{$_}++ for @things;
```

Comment: I just noticed that after I posted, but thanks for the speedy reply. I realized named variables in a single statement are a bit of overkill.

Comment: could you point, please, where this syntax is documented? The perlsyn page dosn't mention this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
foreach my $thing (@things) {$hash{$thing}++};
```

if you want it on one line with a lexically-scoped variable. You can't invert the `foreach` and keep the loop-scoped variable.

Comment: You wrote "You can't invert the `foreach` and keep the loop-scoped variable." Not by that name, no, but so what? A one-line `foreach` doesn’t need a named topicalizer. `$hash{$_}++ for @things` says hash **it** for each thing, or more Englishly, to hash **its** things.  Remember that `$_` should read as "it". And "it" is *guaranteed* to be a loop-scoped variable. Furthermore it will be a brand-new private variable that’s lexically scoped to the loop **IFF** if an extant lexical by that name (read: `$_`) was already in scope, and dynamically scoped otherwise. It is still loop-scoped either way.